# ES6 WeakMap получить список значений или получить событие о сборке мусора объекта

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

В ES6 есть [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)

По описанию

> В нативных WeakMap, ссылки на объекты-ключи хранятся "слабо", что
>   означает то, что они не предотвратят сборку мусора в том случае, если
>   других ссылок на объект не будет.

Но как получить список значений из него? Например я могу сопоставить объект с уникальным значением (GUID). Это нужно для освобождения ресурсов по аналогии с финализатором в C#.

Или есть другие методы узнать, что объект подвергся сборке мусора?

А как можно equals задать? То есть можно держать копию объекта с одинаковым ключевым полем?

Правда нашел ссылку на возможность финализатора https://www.npmjs.com/package/finalize

```
var finalize = require('finalize');
 
var obj = { x: 1337 };
finalize(obj, function () {
  console.log(this.x); // this will print '1337' 
});
global.gc();
// nothing will happen, var obj above holds obj alive 
obj = null;
global.gc();
// the previous line should trigger the callback above
```

Внутри этот метод использует https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-weak

```
var weak = require('weak')

// we are going to "monitor" this Object and invoke "cleanup"
// before the object is garbage collected
var obj = {
    a: true
  , foo: 'bar'
}

// Here's where we set up the weak reference
var ref = weak(obj, function () {
  // `this` inside the callback is the EventEmitter.
  console.log('"obj" has been garbage collected!')
})

// While `obj` is alive, `ref` proxies everything to it, so:
ref.a   === obj.a
ref.foo === obj.foo

// Clear out any references to the object, so that it will be GC'd at some point...
obj = null

//
//// Time passes, and the garbage collector is run
//

// `callback()` above is called, and `ref` now acts like an empty object.
typeof ref.foo === 'undefined'
```

Answer (score 0):

[https://learn.javascript.ru/set-map#weakmap-и-weakset](https://learn.javascript.ru/set-map#weakmap-%D0%B8-weakset)

У WeakMap есть ряд ограничений:

- Нет свойства size.
- Нельзя перебрать элементы итератором или forEach.
- Нет метода clear().

Вывод: остается использовать метод has, чтобы узнать существует ли объект или нет.

Comment: А как можно equals задать? То есть можно держать копию объекта с одинаковым полем?

Answer (score 0):

В [описании](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) ясно написано что из-за реализации этой вундервафли, перебор ключей и, следовательно, значений невозможен.

> Из-за того, что ссылки являются слабыми, ключи WeakMap не перечисляемы
>   (то есть нет метода, который возвращает список ключей). Иначе список
>   бы зависел от состояния сбора мусора, представляя индетерминизм. Если
>   Вы хотите иметь список ключей, Вам следует поддерживать его
>   самостоятельно.

Нет ключей, нет значений.

Если Вам нужен будет перебор, используйте другие конструкции, которые не зависят от сборщика мусора. Тот же [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Comment: Мне как раз нужно узнать подвергся объект сборке мусора или нет. Ладно посмотрю в сторону финализатора https://www.npmjs.com/package/finalize

Comment: Реализовать отслеживание можно. Но не не нужно, ибо зачем? В JS сборщик как Серый Кардинал - он есть, но его нет.

Comment: Ну я так понимаю можно и принудительно вызвать global.gc(); при достижении определенного количества ссылок